# Column- and row-wise logical operations on Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

In Pandas, one can perform boolean operations on boolean DataFrames with the `all` and `any` methods, providing an `axis` argument. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = dict(A=["a","b","?"], B=["d","?","f"])
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For example, to get a boolean mask on columns containing the element "?":

```py
(pd_df == "?").any(axis=0)
```

and to get a mask on rows:

```py
(pd_df == "?").any(axis=1)
```

Also, to get a single boolean:

```py
(pd_df == "?").any().any()
```

In comparison, in `polars`, the best I could come up with are the following:

```py
import polars as pl
pl_df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

To get a mask on columns:

```py
(pl_df == "?").select(pl.all().any())
```

To get a mask on rows:

```py
pl_df.select(
        pl.concat_list(pl.all() == "?").alias("mask")
).select(
    pl.col("mask").arr.eval(pl.element().any()).arr.first()
)
```

And to get a single boolean value:

```py
pl_df.select(
        pl.concat_list(pl.all() == "?").alias("mask")
).select(
    pl.col("mask").arr.eval(pl.element().any()).arr.first()
)["mask"].any()
```

The last two cases seem particularly verbose and convoluted for such a straightforward task, so I'm wondering whether there are shorter/faster equivalents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one thing that might be making this more confusing is that you're not doing everything in the select context. In other words, don't do this: `(pl_df == "?")`

The first thing we can do is

```
pl_df.select(pl.all()=="?")
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ A     ┆ B     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ true  │
│ true  ┆ false │
└───────┴───────┘
```

When we call `pl.all()` it means all of the columns. For each column we're converting its original value into a bool of whether or not it's equal to ?

Now let's do this:

```
pl_df.select((pl.all()=="?").any())

shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ A    ┆ B    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ bool ┆ bool │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ true ┆ true │
└──────┴──────┘
```

This gives you the per column. All we did was add `.any` which tells it that if anything in the parenthesis that preceded it is true then return True.

Now let's do

```
pl_df.select(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all()=="?"))

shape: (3, 1)
┌───────┐
│ any   │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ false │
│ true  │
│ true  │
└───────┘
```

When we call `pl.any_horizontal(...)` then it is going to do that rowwise for whatever `...` is.

Lastly, if we put them together...

```
pl_df.select(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all()=="?").any())

shape: (1, 1)
┌──────┐
│ any  │
│ ---  │
│ bool │
╞══════╡
│ true │
└──────┘
```

then we get the single value indicating that somewhere in the dataframe is an item that is equal to "?"

Comment: We should add this on documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess what threw me off was the section of the user guide about row-wise computations (https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html). So, I also agree with Igor :)

Answer (score 4):

**[Update]:** [Polars 0.18.7](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.18.7) added dedicated horizontal functions for "row-wise" operations.

- [`.all_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html)
- [`.any_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html)

---

- all

```
>>> df.select(pl.all() == "?")
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ A     ┆ B     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ false │
│ false ┆ true  │
│ true  ┆ false │
└───────┴───────┘
```

- col

```
>>> df.select((pl.all() == "?").any())
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ A    ┆ B    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ bool ┆ bool │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ true ┆ true │
└──────┴──────┘
```

- row

```
>>> df.select(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all() == "?"))
shape: (3, 1)
┌───────┐
│ any   │
│ ---   │
│ bool  │
╞═══════╡
│ false │
│ true  │
│ true  │
└───────┘
```

- single

```
>>> df.select(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all() == "?").any())
shape: (1, 1)
┌──────┐
│ any  │
│ ---  │
│ bool │
╞══════╡
│ true │
└──────┘
```

Comment: We should add this on ducumentation.